# Convert epoch time to date in titanium

Tags: javascript, php, date, titanium, epoch

I have epoch times stored in my database like so: 1392821307. These were picked up on a separate web service using the php time() function. I need to convert this to a date/month/year format in Titanium.

So far I have used the following code based off an answer here in stack overflow

```
var utcSeconds = Jobs_data.Jobs[i].DatePosted;
var d = new Date(0); // The 0 there is the key, which sets the date to the epoch
d.setUTCSeconds(utcSeconds);
```

This returns a string like so:

```
Wed Feb 19 14:48:27 GMT 2014
```

I only need the Feb 19 2014. So I'm wondering how to parse this string. I was going to use substring but then for example, Mon will have 3 letters and thurs will have 4, so the starting index of where to parse is changing. Not sure if the month will be of varying length also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d` is actually a date object. If you pass that to Ti.API.info, or console.log, it'll be coerced in to the string that you see above. You should use its `getDate`, `getMonth`, and `getFullYear` methods to get the string that you want.

```
var formattedString = (d.getMonth()+1) + '/' + d.getDate() + '/' + d.getFullYear();
```

Alternatively, use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), which is included in Alloy apps, and can be easily downloaded in to vanilla Titanium apps too:

```
var moment = require('alloy/moment'),
    dm = moment(d),
    formattedString = dm().format('L');
```

This is answered quite simply by a SO answer already:

[Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: I am ussing titanium classic not aloy, so I went with your first approach. Having tried your code, I am receiving a string in the following format: 12/2/114. My exact code is:                 var utcSeconds = MyJobs_data.Jobs[i].DatePosted; JUST REALISED MY MISTAKE, SHOULD BE GETFULLYEAR
var d = new Date(0); 
d.setUTCSeconds(utcSeconds);
var date=d.getDate();
var month=(d.getMonth()+1);
var year=d.getYear();   
var FullDate= date+'/'+month+'/'+year;

Comment: Even if you're not using Alloy, you can download moment.js from the link I provided above, drop it in your Resources directory, `require` it, and take approach 2.